# Know if a date(weekday) is bettween two other dates(weekedaysº)

Tags: objective-c

Im trying to know if the current day of the week + and hour is in between of 2 other weekday + hour.

Let's say, right now is "Tuesday 16:26" and there is an interval that starts with "Tuesday 16:00" and "Tuesday 22:00" so it should return YES.

Im creating dates from the previous strings, and this function tells me if it's in the interval.
This function is part of a class, whose attributes "fechaInicio" and "fechaFin" are start date and end adate respectively.

```
- (BOOL)dateInInterval:(NSDate *)testDate {
    // date1 is the instance variable containing the starting date
    // date2 is the instance variable containing the ending date
    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en"] autorelease]];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE HH:mm"];    
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.fechaInicio];

    NSLog(@"La fecha es: %@", dateString);

    dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.fechaFin];

    NSLog(@"La fecha es: %@", dateString);

    NSLog(@"time interval nicio: %d", [testDate timeIntervalSinceDate:self.fechaInicio]);
    NSLog(@"time interval fin: %d", [testDate timeIntervalSinceDate:self.fechaFin]);

    return ([testDate timeIntervalSinceDate:self.fechaInicio] > 0 &&
            [testDate timeIntervalSinceDate:self.fechaFin] < 0);
}
```

The thing is that in never returns YES, even though I can see the date is in the interval. Im afraid how Im turning the string to date. I input "Tuesday 16:00" what year is it, what month, if I format the actual date to "EEEE HH" will it save the month and year?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For your case, I'd advice to find some fixed known date for Monday and apply the full date for each EEEE HH:mm string. This will give correct values inside date and i think your logic will start working

Comment: I checked and the fixed dates are set to be in 1970, which makes sense, so the question is, how to set the current weekeday to January to 1970?

Comment: What I mean, is was just use real full dates; for example, you take Nov 7th, 2011 for Monday, Nov 8th for Tuesday, Nov 9th for Wednesday and etc. So you have 7 real dates (may be stored in dictionary, where key is Monday, Tuesday & etc) and what you need - just to take copies of those dates for each of your three items and set correct hours. After that comparing will work without any issues.